# How to show the virtual machine name instead of the extension name in this policy?

Tags: json, azure-policy

I've made the following Azure Policy to determine if an extension have been provisioned by Azure Active Directory so I have a way to know if a machine have the AD addon installed. However, although the policy works, it shows the extension name instead of the virtual machine it is deployed. In other words, rather than checking if the virtual machine has the AD extension deployed, it checks if the extension was provisioned by Azure.ActiveDirectory.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions"
        },
        {
          "AnyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
              "notEquals": "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/publisher",
              "exists": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Se puede elegir si desactivar o auditar cuando no se ha instalado el addon del AD en las máquinas virtuales",
        "portalReview": true
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Audit"
    }
  }
}
```

I've checked that extensions installed in the virtual machines can be found inside the parameter called "resources" at the end of the VM json. However, those have no alias so it has to be done through "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions". Any idea on how to solve this one?

Comment: This looks more like something for https://devops.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had a similar case a year or so ago. And I do not remember that it could be solved. As you said, no aliases exist, so right now, your `type` is `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions` and not just the `virtualMachines`, which means it is evaluating each VM extension rather than a VM name. To show the VM name instead, you need to evaluate the VMs and check if they have the desired extension.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Policy, the `type` field in the `if` condition refers to the `resource type` being evaluated. In your case, it is `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions`, which means the policy is evaluating each VM extension. That is why the policy shows the extension name instead of the VM name.

To show the VM name instead, you need to evaluate the VMs and check if they have the desired extension. However, **Azure Policy does not support checking nested resources** like VM extensions when evaluating a parent resource like a VM.

A workaround could be to use Azure Policy to audit VMs that do not have the desired extension, and then use `Azure Resource Graph` (ARG) to query the non-compliant VMs and their extensions. This way, you can see which VMs do not have the desired extension.

You can try this Azure Resource Graph query to search the VMs and their extensions:

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend
    JoinID = toupper(id),
    OSName = tostring(properties.osProfile.computerName),
    OSType = tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType),
    VMSize = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize)
| join kind=leftouter(
    Resources
    | where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions'
    | extend
        VMId = toupper(substring(id, 0, indexof(id, '/extensions'))),
        ExtensionName = name
) on $left.JoinID == $right.VMId
| summarize Extensions = make_list(ExtensionName) by id, OSName, OSType, VMSize
| order by tolower(OSName) asc
```

This query will return a list of VMs and their extensions, which you can then filter to find the VMs that do not have the desired extension. Run via `Azure Resource Graph Explorer`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli&wt.mc_id=MVP_323223#list-all-extensions-installed-on-a-virtual-machine